# UITableViewController doesn't show content when embedded in a Container in another UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiview, containers

What I basically did was that I embedded a UITableViewController into a container in another UIView. Background is, that in a normal TableView, I would not be able to set static cells and load icons in the lines individually for each cell. I followed these steps which I found online:

1. Drag a ViewController onto your storyboard.
2. Drag a TableViewController onto your storyboard.
3. Next Drag a Container view to your ViewController and size it about
   the size you want (smaller than the view) -> when you drag the
   container view it will create a segue and another view. Remove that segue and view.
4. Finally ctrl click in your container and drag to your new
   TableViewContoller. Select Embed.

My result looks like this:

[Screenshot from xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOsjX.png)

The problem is now, that my Container doesn't show the content. It shows that it is a table, but basically an empty one and not the little icons or textfields which should be there. See here:

[Screenshot from Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cf0h.png)

Do you guys have any suggestions what I did wrong or what can I do to show the content? If you need more information please comment. Thx for your help!

Matt

Comment: Looks like that should work. Have you set up the auto layout constraints on the table view cells?

Comment: Hello Dave, actually yes. All the layout constraints are fine! =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. I basically took out the tableViews datasource in EditProfileContainerTableViewController. This was the code which made the problems:

```
        // MARK: - Table view data source

//    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
//        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
//        return 1
//    }
//
//    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
//        return 5
//    }
```

I added an screenshot for you guys, if anybody has a similar problem he can contact me. I'm happy to help :)

[image: EditProfileContainerTableViewController]

Answer (score 2):

1)It might be happening because your `delegate` will be `tableViewController` not View controller.
2)So instead of adding `tableViewController` add `TableView`  in `ViewController` & write `delegate` & `datasource` methods in `ViewController`

Comment: Can you add the code how it should be written please? Can't imagine what you specifically mean.

Comment: You need to add tableView inside EditProfileviewController instead of segueing.Also you need to write delegate datasource code inside EditProfileviewController .Make sure you set delegate & datasource of tableView to be EditProfileviewController

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Basically you can't have static cells and keep the TableView datasource section (i.e. by default the number of sections and number of rows per section function). When the controller loads, it will recreate dynamic cells according to these functions thus hiding your static cells